# How to find the missing size range between two size ranges in Oracle?

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, left-join, outer-join

I want to validate the missing size range between the two size ranges. For example, now I have a table called AQL which have following columns:

```
    ID  TYPE        SIZE_FROM  SIZE_TO
    --  ----------  ---------  -------
    68  NORMAL      2          150
    69  NORMAL      501        1200
    70  REDUCED     1201       3200
    71  REDUCED     151        500
```

I need to find out the missing ranges which are:

```
    TYPE       SIZE_FROM  SIZE_TO
    ---------  ---------  -------
    NORMAL     151        500
    REDUCED    2          150
    REDUCED    501        1200
```

I've been handled the overlapping, so what should I do to select the following missing ranges?

Comment: Not very clear as in how to identify the range. Looking at the expected output, it seems simple where clause with filtering condition.

Comment: Really just using where clause to find out the range? How?

Comment: When you say range , what you actually means ? I cannot see any correlation when you say range.

Comment: For example, like 1-5, 11-15, 16-20, 26-30, so I want to find out the missing ranges are from 6 to 10 and from 21 to 25. This is what I mean.

Comment: In that case  `REDUCED    501        1200` should be `NORMAL      501        1200`.. Isnt it ? You changed the type as well.

Comment: Nope, each type have its own size, Normal type have 2 to 1200 if max is 1200, Reduced type have 2 to 3200 if max is 3200.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For sample data, see if this helps (read comments within code):

```
SQL> with
  2  aql (id, type, size_from, size_to) as
  3    -- Your current data
  4    (select 68, 'NORMAL' ,   2,  150  from dual union all
  5     select 69, 'NORMAL' ,  501, 1200 from dual union all
  6     select 70, 'REDUCED', 1201, 3200 from dual union all
  7     select 71, 'REDUCED',  151,  500 from dual
  8    ),
  9  existing_sizes as
 10    -- list all existing sizes, one-by-one, per type
 11    (select  type, size_from + column_value - 1 csize
 12     from aql cross join table(cast(multiset(select level from dual
 13                                             connect by level <= size_to - size_from + 1
 14                                            ) as sys.odcinumberlist))
 15    ),
 16  minmax as
 17    -- find MIN and MAX size valze per type - will be used in ALLSIZES CTE
 18    (select type, min(size_from) size_from, max(size_to) size_to
 19     from aql
 20     group by type
 21    ),
 22  allsizes as
 23    -- list all sizes (per type) between MIN and MAX value
 24    (select type, size_from + column_value - 1 csize
 25     from minmax cross join table(cast(multiset(select level from dual
 26                                                connect by level <= size_to - size_from + 1
 27                                               ) as sys.odcinumberlist))
 28    ),
 29  missing_sizes as
 30    -- missing sizes can be found with MINUS set operator
 31    (select a.type, a.csize from allsizes a
 32     minus
 33     select e.type, e.csize from existing_sizes e
 34    )
 35  -- the final result
 36  select type, min(csize) size_from, max(csize) size_to
 37  from missing_sizes
 38  group by type;

TYPE     SIZE_FROM    SIZE_TO
------- ---------- ----------
NORMAL         151        500
REDUCED        501       1200

SQL>
```

This will fail, though, if there are more gaps involved (but that's not what your sample data suggest).

Comment: Ya, you're right, I purposely added another record for Normal Type, it just can retrieve 1st missing gap.

Answer (score 1):

`select ... from dual connect by level <=` syntax might be used to produce rows between extreme values for each type, and those are eliminated through the use of `left join`  after generation of integers row-wise between each range ( size_from & size_to ) for each type again through use of above syntax :

```
with  aql2 as
(
 select type, min(size_from) as size_from , max(size_to) as size_to
   from aql
  group by type
)
select a2.type, min(a2.lvl) as size_from, max(a2.lvl) as size_to
  from (select a2.type, a2.size_from + level - 1 as lvl
          from aql2 a2
         cross join dual d
        connect by level <= a2.size_to - a2.size_from + 1
            and prior a2.type =a2.type
            and prior sys_guid() is not null) a2
  left join (select distinct a.type, a.size_from + level - 1 as lvl
               from aql a
              cross join dual d
             connect by level <= a.size_to - a.size_from + 1
              group by a.type, a.size_from + level - 1) a
    on a2.type = a.type
   and a2.lvl = a.lvl 
 where a.lvl is null
 group by a2.type
```

<kbd>[Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=cfa88f5f51fe284a18667462f3047f4c)</kbd>

Comment: I tried your code but it took long time to load data and still haven't retrieve the data.